# How to get pick list value in master from detail

Tags: apex

I have two objects. Master and Detail. In a For loop I need to check if a picklist on Master is set to "Yes".

I have a trigger on the Detail. How do I traverse to the Master to get that value?

This is approximately what I have but it doesn't seem to get the value.

```
for(Detail__c d : Trigger.new)
{
       if (d.Master__r.picklistField__c == "Yes") {do something}
}
```

Comment: You need to actually query the master object to get the field values...they will not be available in trigger.new

Answer (score 1):

My preferred pattern for doing this is to use `Trigger.new` to requery the records passed in, like this:

```
for (Detail__c d : [SELECT Id, Master__r.picklistfield__c 
                    FROM Detail__c where Id in : Trigger.new]){

  if (d.Master__r.picklistField__c == 'Yes') {
    //do something
  }
}
```